# Есть компонент EditText. Можно ли по какому-нибудь жесту перевести клавиатуру в ввод голосом

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Есть компонент `EditText`. Хочется по какому-нибудь жесту перевести клавиатуру в ввод голосом. Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Под жестом понимается, скажем долгое нажатие по полю EditText.

Comment: так он же встроен уже в editText. не нужно больше никаких фокусов с этим делать.

Comment: заказчик не может попасть значку микрофона

Comment: Ещё подойдёт вариант нажать на пункт меню, и фокус перешёл на editText и клавиатура перешла в режим ввода голосом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно обработать ваш жест и вызвать внешний интент:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
```

теоретически его может и не быть в системе, так что сначала надо проверить его наличие

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
        new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
if (activities.size() == 0) //нет распознавателя
    //blah-blah
```

Если есть вызвать `Activity` распознавателя через `startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST)` и в `onActivityResult()` полученные данные положить в `EditText`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //массив распознанных строк 
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //ложим в EditText

    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**Update**

Собственно ответ на сам вопрос:

> перевести клавиатуру в ввод голосом. Возможно ли такое?

Увы это невозможно. Нет такого `INPUT_TYPE`, каждая реализация клавиатуры реализует сама поддержку ввода голосом.